# how to embed a video into Lotus Notes webpage

Tags: lotus-notes

I want my webpage to show a video automatically. The video file is an attachment in some field on the form that user cannot see. So user needs to see the video itself either in iFrame or somehow else. Please advise.

Domino version 8.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should show what you have tried...

The way I would do it is to use a regular video player and point it to the video file. If it is stored as an attachment, use $FILE to reference it in the URI: http://Host/Database/View/Document/$File/Filename?OpenElement

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Domino_URL_cheat_sheet/ is a good place to look.

If you use video.js for example (http://www.videojs.com/) your code would look something like this:

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
  controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
  data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
 <source src="http://http://www.example.com/database.nsf/0/987A5B7922CC2FB386257EC2004D17A9/$File/videoclip.mp4?OpenElement" type='video/mp4' />
 <source src="http://http://www.example.com/database.nsf/0/987A5B7922CC2FB386257EC2004D17A9/$File/videoclip.webm?OpenElement" type='video/webm' />
 <source src="http://http://www.example.com/database.nsf/0/987A5B7922CC2FB386257EC2004D17A9/$File/videoclip.ogv?OpenElement" type='video/ogg' />
 <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Martinsson.. I was just wondering if I can use something standard of Lotus Notes but not like video.js.. But it may work

Comment: I thought it should be something like form "Create->Object->FlashPlayer"

Comment: Create - Object is for embedded OLE objects. You can't embed the content for an object in a regular field. It would have to be rich text - and I don't think the Domino server renders embedded OLE objects to the browser.